# JAR file does not load class files from ext

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I installed JDK 1.6 on my Linux system, the $JAVA _HOME directory is `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07`.
I built the path on Eclipse to $JAVA_HOME. It runs smoothly through Eclipse and loads all third party JAR files from `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07/jre/lib/ext/`, but when I export the JAR file and run it, it throws `ClassNotFoundExecption`.

Why?

Comment: I wouldn't use such an old version of Java as it is four years old. I would include you jar in the class path. What are you doing when you say you "export the jar file"?

Comment: *"loads all third party JAR files from `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07/jre/lib/ext/`"*  That is odd, given they should not be there in the first place.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey export the jar file means when export the jar file from eclipse

Comment: So you are generating a JAR using eclipse. This is fine, but you have to make sure what you have generated will be used but setting the classpath and/or putting it in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey but if I force to do that ,why it is not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you install Java properly? Here are some instruction for installing [Java 7](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) or [Java 6](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-6-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)
2. Are you sure that the version of Java you are using is correct one since there can be several versions of java on linux? Try `java -version` on terminal where you run it to check.
3. Do you use any third party library? If so, did you specify the class path when you run the jar file or bundle them inside your jar file?

Comment: Hi @gigadot,thanks for commenting, java -version returns --java version "1.6.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode) . Should I require to specify the path of jars that are placed in ext ? and how I bundle the jar file and specify class path inside my jar.

Comment: Why did you put your external jar file in ext folder? Usually, they should be in your under your project path for ease of organising. You can specify class path using -cp argument when you start your application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: Thanks, @gigadot , ok I removed the jars from ext, but if I require to have that jars into my jar and they automatically get build when I run it, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What does `java -version` return? Are you using the same JRE for execution?

Comment: Thanks, java -version returns jdk1.6.0_07 and yes I build the path JRE System Library of eclipse to /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07