# oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver exception for Beginners Java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I searched a lot about this error but no solution works.

I'm just learning Java connection with Oracle.

But I'm getting this exception.

```
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I already placed `ojdbc6.jar` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext` now what to do next?

In few days ago I was working fine with database. But recently 2 days ago I reinstall windows not forgot how to setup it.

Here is Complete StackTrace.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at RunQuery.main(RunQuery.java:11)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace? Was it ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: @simdevmon question updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493764/jar-file-does-not-load-class-files-from-ext

Comment: have you placed java in your system's PATH ?

Comment: @svarog I think so, that's why I'm running javac and java commands.

Comment: You shouldn't put DB driver jar in under JDK folder, you need to provide in classpath or  server lib or inside your war file.

Comment: @Viraj I'm not using any war file. I have just installed Oracle and then connecting to Java. in simple code. one line Class.forName(); just checking the driver first.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) link for adding third party jar (ojdbc6.jar)  while running Java program.

and I suggest you to use latest driver jar which is compatible to JDK 8, You can check on this FAQ link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: viraj I already placed `ojdbc14.jar` also but that is also not working. -_-

Comment: 2) For JDK 7 & 8, you should use ojdbc7.jar and 1) java -cp "locationToYourJAR/ojdbc7.jar"  yourpackage.yourmaninmethodclass like this you need to execute your program.  if this still not working, Please share your screen shot of folder structure and output.

Comment: can you visit it please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641994/oracle-installation-product-folder-and-diag-folder-in-different-place